# Complexes question $(z-1) \over (z+1)$

Tags: complex-numbers

> Given $z \ne -1$. Prove that $(z-1) \over (z+1)$ is an Imaginary number if and only if $|z| = 1$.

I tried computing $(z-1) \over (z+1)$ by multiplying like that: $(z-1) \over (z+1)$$(z-1) \over (z-1)$ and then getting: $(z-1)^2$

but if $z = 1$ then it's zero, and it's not an imaginary number. Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe its like $2Im(z-1)^2$ something.. which means it always an Imaginary? I'm not quite sure :(

Comment: You can regard $0=0i$ as an imaginary number in this case. It lies in the intersection of the real axis and the imaginary axis, so it is both real and pure imaginary. It really comes down to how you define pure imaginary -- if you just require that the real part vanishes, this is okay.

Comment: I just got it with $(z-1)(\overline{(z+1)} = (z-1)(\overline{(z)}+\overline{(1))} = (z-1)\overline{(z}+1)$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Multiply numerator and denominator by $z^*+1$:

$$\frac{z-1}{z+1}=\frac{(z-1)(z^*+1)}{|z+1|^2}=\frac{zz^*+z-z^*-1}{|z+1|^2}=
\frac{|z|^2-1+2iIm\{z\}}{|z+1|^2}$$

Obviously, the denominator is real, and so this number is purely imaginary if $|z|^2-1=0$, i.e. if $|z|=1$.

Comment: That's exactly what I was about to post--you beat me to it! No need for me to post a duplicate answer then. +1.

Comment: $(z-1)(\overline{(z+1)} = (z-1)(\overline{(z)}+\overline{(1))} = (z-1)\overline{(z}+1)$

Answer (score 5):

I believe you have meant **purely** imaginary

Setting $z=a+ib$ where  $a,b$ are real

$$\frac{z-1}{z+1}=\frac{a+ib-1}{a+ib+1}=\frac{(a-1+ib)(a+1-ib)}{(a+1)^2+b^2}$$

$$=\frac{(a)^2-(1-ib)^2}{(a+1)^2+b^2}=\frac{a^2+b^2-1+2ib}{(a+1)^2+b^2}$$

Comment: This is exactly what the other answer says, written in slightly different notation. (+1)

Comment: Love keeping it complexes with 'z'. Thanks for the answer anyways.

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS, More often than not, I found "keeping it with "$z$ ;  things become too complex

Comment: Good to know that. I'll stick with z for now.